# Creating a widget to allow user to open a dialog box to navigate to a excel file and then select the tab and pass to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, widget, ipywidgets

I want to create widget that allows a user to navigate folders and files to select a file an excel file then choose which sheet is required and then create a pandas dataframe from the selection made.

I am able to get the widget to navigate the folder structure and make a selection, however, the drop down list does not populate with sheet names.

code below

'''

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display

   # Function to read Excel sheet and create a DataFrame
   def read_excel_sheet(file_contents, sheet_name):
     df = pd.read_excel(file_contents, sheet_name=sheet_name)
     return df

       # Create FileUpload widget
       file_upload = widgets.FileUpload()

   # Create Dropdown widget for sheet selection
   sheet_dropdown = widgets.Dropdown(options=[], description='Select Sheet')

   # Function to update dropdown options when file is uploaded
   def update_sheet_dropdown(change):
       uploaded_file = next(iter(file_upload.value))
       file_contents = file_upload.value[uploaded_file]['content']
       excel_file = pd.ExcelFile(file_contents)
       sheet_names = excel_file.sheet_names
       sheet_dropdown.options = sheet_names

   # Event listener for file upload
   file_upload.observe(update_sheet_dropdown, names='value')

   # Display widgets
   display(file_upload)
   display(sheet_dropdown)

   # Function to handle sheet selection and DataFrame creation
   def handle_sheet_selection(change):
       uploaded_file = next(iter(file_upload.value))
       file_contents = file_upload.value[uploaded_file]['content']
       sheet_name = sheet_dropdown.value
       df = read_excel_sheet(file_contents, sheet_name)
       # Use the DataFrame 'df' as desired
       print(df)

    # Event listener for sheet selection
    sheet_dropdown.observe(handle_sheet_selection, names='value')
```

'''

there are no error messages so not sure things are going wrong.